# How to access json in Node to Angular Error Handling

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am at a loss.

I send errors from node like this:

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {

```
const body = {
    errorMessage: error.message || JSON.stringify(error)
}

const status = error.status || 500;

    res.status(status);
    res.header('Error', error.message);
    res.json(body);
    res.send();


})
```

And I want to display the errorMessage like this in angular:

```
 (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.loadingSpinner.stopLoading();

      console.log(error.error); // {"errorMessage": "Here is the errorMessage"}
      console.log(error.error.errorMessage); // undefined
    });
```

What do I wrong? Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

JSON.parse(error.error).errorMessage was the solution.